# UnhandledAlertException : The element can be executed but does not clicked in system

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The element for "Contact" can be clicked but for the "Equity" which the next line can be executed but does not clicked in the system. The system still shows the "Contact" page. In eclipse, it shows the Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: :

The code is

```
Actions linktext1 = new Actions(driver);
WebElement contact = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Contact')]"));
linktext1.moveToElement(contact).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Contact')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick=\"navigateTo('CompanyCustomerEquity.do?event=edit_prepare_company_customer_equity')\"]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Ownership')]")).click();
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: It sounds like the first click causes an alert to popup that needs to be dealt with before proceeding. Put a breakpoint on the first click line and run it. Once it stops, step one line at a time and see what happens after the first click. Once you do that, come back and edit and update the question with that info if you still don't know how to handle the issue.

Comment: I already put the breakpoint and it shows that the first click cause the alert to pop up. Thus, i put the thread.sleep(2000) and it works.

Comment: Do the first click, handle the alert by accepting or cancelling, and then continue on with the script. I don't understand what the sleep accomplishes?